# Getting User Data Based on Their Information

Tags: php, mysql

This first field is where a web visitor will enter in the 'cardname' hit submit and be directed to another page (dashboard2.php) where only his or her content will appear.

```
Enter your cardname to access your content<br>
<form action='dashboard2.php'>
<input type='text' name='cardname'/><input type='submit' value='retrieve card'/>
</form>
</body>
```

The page below is the page that is directed after the user enters in the 'cardname' from the first input field. However, I only want this second page to show the information based on the cardname that was entered. Right now, it shows every single cardname, questionone, answerone from that table.

```
    <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "flashcards";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT cardname, questionone, answerone FROM cards";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     // output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         echo "<br> ". $row["cardname"]. "  ". $row["questionone"]. " " . $row["answerone"] . "<br>";
     }
} else {
     echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();

?>
```

Comment: As @JayBlanchard said and add `method="post"` to your form tag

Comment: And now that you'll be taking $_POST data and using it in your SQL query, I'd recommend utilizing prepared statements.

Comment: You're not doing anything with your form.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems that you want to perform a search and not a display all the records.
Usually a search returns records that match a certain field, unless a specific ID or unique value was entered in the search. I'm not sure this is the case.

I put this together a little quick but hopefully it helps...

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "flashcards";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// escape the string to avoid SQL injections
$searchEscaped = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['cardname']);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT cardname, questionone, answerone FROM cards WHERE cardname = '$searchEscaped' ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    if($result->num_rows == 1){
        // only one result found, show just that
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc()
        echo "<br> ". $row["cardname"]. "  ". $row["questionone"]. " " . $row["answerone"] . "<br>"; 
    }else{
        // multiple rows found, show them all
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
             echo "<br> ". $row["cardname"]. "  ". $row["questionone"]. " " . $row["answerone"] . "<br>";
         }
    }

} else {
     echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();

?>
```

Comment: Good answer, but there's no point in doing `if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    if($result->num_rows == 1){` - One will suffice.

Comment: you do have a syntax error here though `$row = $result->fetch_assoc()`. either a missing semi-colon, or a `while` loop.

Comment: fred -ii- that semi-colon did the charm! Thank you.

Comment: @atokad5 However, this answer needs to be edited accordingly and for future readers to the question that may not know what to do with it. You should tell Ethan that. It's not up to us to fix other people's answers ;-)

Comment: @atokad5 Thing is though. This answer contains POST arrays and your form doesn't have a POST method (forms default to GET if a POST method isn't implied), unlike Jay's answer who outlined everything perfectly. In my view and for others I'm sure, you accepted the wrong answer. But hey, that's up to you. I won't tell you what to do, just to say that this answer doesn't reflect the question/code you posted. This is important for future readers to the question/answers. **Nota:** This isn't preferential treatment, it's the answer that counts and that showed the flaws in your code and the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have to modify the query to accept a `WHERE` clause. For instance, `WHERE cardname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['cardname'])` (*The default method for any form is GET unless you specify `method="post"`.*).

You should learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and perhaps consider using PDO, [it's really not hard](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).